# Find domain of $Y=\sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1 + \sqrt{14-x}\,}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How do I get the domain of
$$
Y = \sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1 + \sqrt{14-x}\,}?
$$

I know that $\lfloor x \rfloor - 1 + \sqrt{14-x} > 0$ and $14-x>0$ and the maximum value of of $x$ must be $14$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: *Notation:* You can use `\lfloor x \rfloor` to render the floor function: $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to the previous solution but perhaps a little simpler:

At first just work with $x$.

Find where $x-1+ \sqrt{14-x}\geq 0$ which is $[\frac{1-\sqrt{53}}{2},14]\approx[-3.14,14]$

Then note that $\lfloor{x}\rfloor \leq -4$ when $x<-3$.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "getting the domain"? Do you mean writing the domain as an interval or a collection of intervals? Because if you just want to write down the domain, you already have an answer
$$
D = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \lfloor x \rfloor -1+\sqrt{14-x} \ge 0 \wedge 14 -x \ge 0 \}.
$$

As it turns out, $D = ]-3,14]$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the inner root term, x must be ***less than or equal to 14*** so the term [x] will have its *maximum value=14* and not the minimum value...

Now, the inner root term will give a positive result or 0, which basically means that all positive numbers less than or equal to 14 will occur in its domain..

Now breaking x into the floor part(integral part(I)-1)+fractional part(F) and substituting and squaring, then substituting x as I, you will get the answer as ***(-3,14]***

Comment: Your stated answer is $(-5,14]$ however $-3.5$ does not work. $\lfloor {-3.5}\rfloor-1+\sqrt{14+3.5}<0$. We need to make sure the floor is no more than $-3$ so it is $(-3,14]$.

Comment: I meant no **less** than $-3$

Comment: oh my bad i regarded it as the ceiling, thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).